# Laravel Custom Validation with Extra Parameters

Tags: validation, laravel-5, php-7, change-password

Is is possible to add extra parameters to a custom validation rule other than just `$attribute` and `$value`?

I'm implementing a Change-Password function. I want to create a custom rule that checks for the input `password` against the user's password hash and notifies if the user has entered the right password before applying the password-change.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could normally have "required" validation check first on "password" field and then match it with the hash and return error if its not a match like so:

```
// normal required validation
...
//check for correct password
$password = $request->input('password');
if (!Hash::check($password, $hashedPassword))
{
    //return error
}
```

Of course, you need to fetch `$hashedPassword` from the currently logged in user.